# Prove that the intersection of $BM$ and $CN$ is on the circumcircle of triangle $ABC.$

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

Let $P$ and $Q$ be on segment $BC$ of an acute triangle $ABC$ such that $\angle PAB$ = $\angle BCA$ and $\angle CAQ = \angle ABC$.Let $M$ and $N$ be the points on $AP$ and $AQ$, respectively, such that $P$ is the midpoint of $AM$ and $Q$ is the midpoint of $AN$.Prove that the intersection of $BM$ and $CN$ is on the circumcircle of triangle $ABC.$

Comment: What have you attempted to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\angle PBM= \alpha$ and $\angle NCQ=\beta$. Then, as $BP$ is the median of $\triangle ABM$, we have that $\cot \alpha +\cot (\pi-A)=\cot B+\cot A$, which gives $\cot \alpha = 2\cot A+\cot B$ and similarly $\cot \beta = 2\cot A+\cot C$. For convenience, let us take $\cot A=c_1$, $\cot B=c_2$ and $\cot C=c_3$.

By the addition formula we have:

$$\cot(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\cot \alpha \cot\beta-1}{\cot\alpha+\cot\beta}$$
$$=\frac{(2c_1+c_2)(2c_1+c_3)-1}{4c_1+c_2+c_3}=\frac{4c_1^2+2c_1c_2+2c_1c_3+c_2c_3-1}{4c_1+c_2+c_3}$$

To prove that the intersection of $BM$ and $CN$ (call it $X$) is on the circumcircle, we need to prove that $\angle AXC=180^{\circ}-A$, or $\cot(\alpha+\beta)=\cot A$.

To do so, we use the identity, $\tan A+\tan B+\tan C= \tan A\tan B \tan C$ when $A+B+C=\pi$, which gives $c_1c_2+c_1c_3+c_2c_3=1$. Thus,

$$\cot(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{4c_1^2+c_1c_2+c_1c_3+(c_1c_2+c_1c_3+c_2c_3)-1}{4c_1+c_2+c_3}=c_1=\cot A$$

$\text{QED}$.

Comment: (+1) Despite being a trigonometric solution, it is rather clean, I like it.

Comment: @Sawarnik Congrats! You have solved the IMO 2014 question!I'll make sure to ask the doubts sir.

Comment: @Sawarnik Ok now a series of doubts evade my mind after going through ur solution as I have no idea about trigonometry.First how is $\cot \alpha +\cot A=\cot B+\cot (\pi-A)$?Is this any property or theorem kind of?? Second how can we say that "To prove that the intersection of $BM$ and $CN$ (call it X) is on the circumcircle, we need to prove that $∠AXC=180∘−A$, or $cot(α+β)=cotA$."Make both parts of the statement clear please.Sorry don't take it seriously because I am a dumbo!

Comment: @SNEHILSINHA Can you come to the chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13523/the-root-of-math :D
We can discuss it there :)

Comment: @What if points p and q interchange their positions?It is not mentioned in the question as where to take both the points??

Comment: @Sawarnik Can you please explain the whole process how did you get c_1c_2+c_2c_3+c_3c_1=1?

Comment: @SNEHILSINHA sure come to chat..